# Installing and maintaining Nginx + php-fpm from source: best practices

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

So I finally have Nginx + php-fpm running and all the various conf files and logging working. All done from `yum`. But given the limits of what I get with this approach -- older Nginx, older PHP -- I'd like to install from source.

Instead of making this a broad open-ended best practice question, I'd like to ask if there's a way to install both Nginx and PHP-FPM while retaining the old conf files for each? The core files could change and be updated, but the conf should remain.

Thank you for any thoughts or pointers.

Comment: What distro are you on and how old are the ones from yum? Presumably it would be possible to get newer binaries by adding an external repository, no?

Comment: Download source, build in a temporary location, deploy binaries. Conf files aren't typically touched.

Comment: Thank you. @nafg, I am on CentOS 7.2. What external repo could I add, so that a simple `yum update nginx` will be enough? I'm also interested in php7-fpm, which is a similar issue.

Comment: @Tim, can I do this with both nginx and php-fpm, and just 'replace' the old binaries with the new ones, while keeping conf etc intact? That sounds promising.

Comment: That's what i do, but I don't mind doing restarts of services and losing the odd connection. I wrote a blog article on this, but it mostly references a DO tutorial as I'm not a Linux expert. https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/upgrade-running-nginx-amazon-linux/ and  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-nginx-in-place-without-dropping-client-connections  .